# is there any way I can open multiple terminals on the xfce4 window automatically every time I start xfce4?

Tags: shell, terminal, window, xfce

I'm doing some experiments and while I do it I have to turn a board off and on frequently (a program doesn't get killed properly probably with unclosed socket .. I installed signal handler and it worked and now it doesn't..) . Every time I turn on the board, I start vnc window (it starts xfce4 ) and have to open terminals in specific location. Is there any setup method through which the terminals are open automatically in specific locations? Or further with specific number of tabs? (I know how to give xwindow location and size : xwininfo -all. and use -geometry 1000x1000+300+300 for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you could add commands to the application autostart menu in Settings > Session and startup and give the command the working directory as an option as follows:

```
xfce4-terminal --default-working-directory="/home/$USER/Desktop"
```

The different options available are:

```
OPTIONS
   Option Summary
       Here is a summary of all the options, grouped by type. Explanations are in the following sections.



   General Options
       -h, --help; -V, --version; --disable-server; --color-table; --default-display=display;
       --default-working-directory=directory

   Window or Tab Separators
       --tab; --window

   Tab Options
       -x, --execute; -e, --command=command; -T, --title=title; --dynamic-title-mode=mode;
       --initial-title=title; --working-directory=directory; -H, --hold; --active-tab;
       --color-text=color; --color-bg=color

   Window Options
       --display=display; --drop-down; --geometry=geometry; --role=role; --startup-id=string; -I,
       --icon=icon; --fullscreen; --maximize; --minimize; --show-menubar, --hide-menubar;
       --show-borders, --hide-borders; --show-toolbar, --hide-toolbar; --show-scrollbar,
       --hide-scrollbar; --font=font; --zoom=zoom
```

Refer to the man page for more settings related to tabs and windows.

```
man xfce4-terminal
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try that when I get back to work. (wow I went to work this morning but immediately was sent home because there is someone in our building who has a covid-19 symptom.)

Comment: I tried that and could make two windows in my wanted positions, both with 4 tabs. But I can't figure out how to set the default-working-directory (for one tab it worked, but with 4 tabs, it didn't. maybe I have to give the value for all tabs..)